# Power Query - FIFO Inventory Valuation

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, fifo

We had experienced a problem with our inventory valuation in DAX, as we got a circular dependency. As DAX is not capable of recursion, we are pretty sure to solve this problem with power query functions.

Problem is the following:

Assuming i start with an initial stock: QTY 900000, Price 0,3 and I also have my monthly Sales QTY and Purchase QTY and price I could create the following (the Excel with the formulas for 2 months is attached)

[image: Example for Month 1]

Then, in the next month I would "just" need to take my closing inventory price as my opening price.
This is where the problem sits as it would need to be calculated first and then referencing itself while defining the formula like so:

```
openingunitrate=

if "initialstockunitrate"=blank() then
    inventoryfromopening(monthyear-1)*openingunitrate(monthyear-1)+
    inventoryfrompurchases(monthyear-1)*purchaseunitrate(monthyear-1)
/
    closingstock(monthyear-1)

else

     "initialstockunitrate"
```

Also what would need to be done is a grouping per "Category" and the column compliance_year. It should start in the next year with 0 as we only have an initial stock this year.

I don't know if this will actually require a recursive function in PowerQuery, so if you have any other idea how to solve it, it's fine as well! In my head this logic totally makes sense but as I have little experince with PQ I'm struggling to actually code it there.

I attached an Excel file that includes both the calculation done in Excel and the sample data which would need to be enhanced.

Please find it under the following link:

[Sample Data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1f1fLeeA-QM9Mx5CKSD2SsCQyyQ4FrJJk/view?usp=sharing)

thanks and regards,

Martin